# How to present a view controller from a detached view controller?

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to present a view controller modally and get the famous `Presenting view controllers on detached view controllers is discouraged` error. I researched it and the consensus solution appears to be making the presentation from the parent, which I tried but did not have success with. I suspect the problem is because the navigation controller was instantiated from a struct as a static property (to make it easier for other view controller's to pop to root as this is what the UX called for).

```
struct SectionNavigationControllers {
    static var one = SectionNavigationController()
    static var two = SectionNavigationController()
    static var three = SectionNavigationController()
    static var four = SectionNavigationController()
}
```

And here is where one of the navigation controllers is created (using this struct):

```
let SectionOneRoot = MasterSearchViewController()

func addNavigationController() {

    self.addChildViewController(SectionOneRoot)
    SectionOneRoot.didMove(toParentViewController: self)
    SectionNavigationControllers.one = SectionNavigationController(rootViewController: SectionOneRoot)
    view.addSubview(SectionNavigationControllers.one.view)

}
```

And so when I try to present a view controller modally from `MasterSearchViewController` (the root view controller), I get the said error.

```
navigationController?.present(Random200ViewController(), animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Ideas?

Comment: get the app main Window, then get a reference to the root view controller; you should be able to use it to present the new view controller

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a convenience function you can add to any piece of code to present a view controller from anywhere in your app:

```
func showModally(_ viewController: UIViewController) {
    let window = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow
    let rootViewController = window?.rootViewController
    rootViewController?.present(viewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

I hope it helps!

Comment: It worked perfectly, thank you! Is this the preferred way of presenting view controllers or is there some degree of "hackery" involved here?

Comment: @sconewolf Typically you would present the view controller from the currently presented view controller and not the root view controller of the app.  Sometime though simpler is better, and if trying to locate the currently active view controller is too much trouble, this is a nice way of doing things.

Comment: And if I presented it this way and wanted to use a UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning object to create a custom animation, which view controller needs to conform to the protocol and call the duration and animation object methods? The application root?

Comment: Unfortunately I believe it has to be the view controller doing the presentation, so in this case the root view controller.  I'm unfamiliar with UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning so you might want to check similar questions or do some experimenting.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to present it on your app's root viewController, you can do it like this:

```
let rootVC = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController

rootVC?.present(Random200ViewController(), animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: Ah, I see @ekscrypto said the same thing above.

Comment: Yes sorry, I was on my mobile device and typing a sample source code was tedious so I limited myself to a comment.  Good job coming up with a similar solution!

Comment: Both of you saved my butt with this and I wish I could give 2 checkmarks but @ekscrypto chimed in just a few minutes before you. But still uprooted you and still appreciate the help!

Comment: Oh, yeah, absolutely. He should get it. Glad your problem is solved!